# Mexican Spiced Mocha Minus Chili Powder

Tags: substitutions, coffee

I like Mexican Spiced Mocha and want to make it at home. But every recipe that I go through has chili powder as an ingredient. I am quite apprehensive abt. it. Can I make this particular coffee leaving chili pwdr and substituting something else in its place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like spiced mocha made elsewhere then you are already having chili powder, so chances are you will like the recipes you would make at home. Substituting something else will change the flavor of the result you get, instead I would modify the amount and type of chili powder you use to get the amount of heat you get. There's a huge variety of chili powders available from very mild to hotter than pain itself, so try a mild chili powder and add less of it than the recipe calls for, if you want more heat add more or use a hotter chili powder.

Comment: Hi @GdD, can you suggest a variety of chili pwdr that would sit perfectly into the recipe of moderately spiced mocha?

Comment: I would suggest starting with an unsmoked sweet paprika (Dulce Pimenton in some places), or just looking for mild chili powder, you often see it marketed as mild, medium or hot.

Comment: I second @GdD dulce pimenton adds the perfect amount of spice without too much heat.

Comment: My upvote is actually for your comment suggesting paprika, since it's a hugely useful substitute for keeping the flavor profile for people who can't handle the heat of chili powder, however mild.  Three thumbs up for mentioning it.

Comment: Chile powder is not necessarily the stuff you buy in a store labeled "Chile powder". That stuff usually contains cumin and other spices as well. I make my own Chile powder by de-seeding and grinding up ripe Hatch/Anaheim type peppers. Lacking Cumin, the flavor is quite different from store-bought Chile powder. It's a *far* more versatile flavoring.

Comment: @user50547 To throw another variety in the ring, I would recommend Ancho chile powder. Ancho chiles have a sweet, smokey, and deep flavor with only a little heat. They are often paired with chocolate, e.g. in mole sauce, and the powder is widely available. Used in moderation, it would complement your mocha without rendering it too spicy.

Comment: Arbol chile also has a nice complex flavor. Used with caution, as it can be quite warm, it complements a lot of dishes.

Answer (score 0):

just skip the chili, no ?

It will not taste the same and won't be spicy.

I assume the recipe uses cinnamon.

You can try with different spices like cardamom, five-spice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recipe I use.

2 to 3 shakes from each of the following
(in powdered form from spice containers that have small holes on top):

- Cinnamon
- Ancho Chili
- Cardamom
- Cayenne Pepper

Just **leave off the Cayenne** for milder spice.